# python multiprocessing AttributeError

Tags: python, multiprocessing, attributeerror

```
import multiprocessing
import time

def worker():
    n=5 #number of process
    while n>0:
        print("the time is {0}".format(time.ctime()))
        time.sleep(2)
        n-=1

if __name__=="__main__":
    p=multiprocessing.Process(target=worker)
    p.start()
    print("end")
```

---

```
3.5.2 |Continuum Analytics, Inc.| (default, Jul  5 2016, 11:41:13) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
Python Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
[evaluate multiprocess.py]
end
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "c:\Users\xxxxx\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 106, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd)
  File "c:\Users\xxxx\Miniconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in _main
    self = pickle.load(from_parent)
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'worker' on <module '__mp_main__' from 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Wing IDE 101 5.1\\src\\debug\\tserver\\_sandbox.py'>
```

I really have no idea how to fix this
Once I use multiprocessing, attribute error would occur
error message always shows AttributeError no matter what I do

Comment: I don't see an issue , I tried in pycharm works perfectly

Comment: Try this  in Anaconda3  instead of MIniconda3

Comment: C:\Anaconda3\python.exe C:/Users/hsingh/PycharmProjects/untitled/Multiprocessing_example.py
end
the time is Wed Nov 22 10:37:18 2017
the time is Wed Nov 22 10:37:20 2017
the time is Wed Nov 22 10:37:22 2017
the time is Wed Nov 22 10:37:24 2017
the time is Wed Nov 22 10:37:26 2017

Process finished with exit code 0

Comment: you have Miniconda, you can easily install Anaconda into it with conda install anaconda

Comment: It just seems a problem about Wing IDE, try to run it from terminal or Pycharm.